# C++ namespace elements

Tags: c++, namespaces

I want to get namespace elements name and value... how can I do that?
I want to list names and values (edited)

example

```
namespace testns{
  int stuff=4;
};

int index=0;

get_element_name(testns,index);
get_element_value(testns,int,index);
```

Comment: `index` is not part of the namespace here. Are you looking for `testns::stuff` or something like [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming))

Comment: I think `enum` may suit you better

Comment: Are you trying to list the names and values of the elements in the namespace?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 4):

A namespace is just what it says on the box, a namespace. You can have the same namespace in many modules, how would you know how to index them? What is the *one and only* proper order? Namespaces are only to categorize elements, not to somehow magically allow them to be indexed.

C++ does not have any reflection facilities (I assume that is what you are looking for). You have to manually state what you want.

Comment: I need a function for this I don't care rules

Comment: "C++ does not have any reflection facilities". There is no function.

Comment: @Dresmor If you want a function for it you'll have to write one. You'll also have to find a tool that parses C++ and generates source code containing the data or a linkable object file. What you are asking for is simply **not** possible with standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is called *reflection,* and C++ doesn't have any language-level built-in way of doing this for you. There are only a few things that can be done, such as using the `#` operator within a `#define`, but then you're using `#define`s, which I bet is not what you want.

The closest thing you can functionally get is to write *another* program which reads your source, digs out the namespace information, then writes it to a header file you can `#include` somewhere else. The [GCC-XML extension](http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html) could be helpful in this regard, since it uses the G++ front end to parse the language, then outputs the syntax trees as XML, which you can read with any number of XML DOM parsers.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the variable stuff, you do this:

```
//Setting
testns::stuff = 10;

//Getting
int stuff_value = testsn::stuff;
```

The purposes of namespaces are to disambiguate between code which use similar nomenclature.